# git showing all files chmod to 100644 from 100755

Tags: git, cygwin, tmux

Today I tried to just install tmux on cygwin and afterwards all of a sudden I was getting changes on all of my files. They all changed permissions from 100755 to 100644 out of no where and I have no way of getting rid of them... I thought `git checkout -- .` or `git reset --hard` would work, but as soon as I run `git status` again, all the files have been modified again.

I have since removed tmux, restarted computer, completely re-cloned the repo, etc and nothing has fixed it... I have no idea what the hell is changing all my files! I know some people say just use `git config core.filemode false` to tell git to not look at the changes, but thats not what I want.  My IIS doesn't work with the new file permissions so I can't just ignore them and move on...

Any ideas?

Comment: By your own admission it appears that Tmux changed the permissions, not Git. Git is not the problem, and Git is not the solution.

Comment: This is interesting.. I'm not sure how `tmux` could have changed file permissions. It's a very well built, non-invasive tool that has nothing to do with permissions of random files. I'd be surprised to find our `tmux` is the root cause of this.

Comment: I have the same problem on my Windows PC at the office using Cygwin+git.  At first, I assumed it was due to onerous internal Active Directory group policies, but now I am less sure.  Related: https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-09/msg00072.html

Answer (score 2):

With a recent Git ([2.9.1 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285462/6309)), try:

```
git add --chmod=+x -- my*.files
```

That should force Git to add those file as 755.
But it is possible that [tmux has an umask](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/why-newly-created-file-permission-always-644-umask-issue-793520/) which forces files to be checked out as 644.
Try cloning again after typing: `umask 002`.