# Problems cloning projects with Cygwin's Git

Tags: git, cygwin, sourcetree

When I try to clone projects using Cygwin's Git 2.7.0 I'm having some issues related to permissions. This is, every time I try running one of the cloned project's executables I'm getting the next error:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

If I instead use Cygwin's Git, the one included in Attlasian SourceTree, projects will be cloned "properly", and I won't be getting any issue. Below I list both Git's global configurations:

Cygwin's Git (2.7.0):

```
user.email=foo@foo.com
user.name=foo
alias.default=!git add -A && git commit -m 'default commit'
core.filemode=false
core.autocrlf=true
```

SourceTree's Git (Git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0):

```
user.name=foo
user.email=foo@foo.com
core.autocrlf=true
core.filemode=false
```

How can I configure Cygwin's Git (or other stuff) properly to avoid having such permissions issues?

Comment: Current cygwin : `$ git --version` 
`git version 2.8.3 ` Are you sure to have a proper cygwin installation ?

Comment: @matzeri I've upgraded the git package to match yours,  `$ git --version git version 2.8.3` but the problem still [persists](http://screencast.com/t/7CV8WYLsUV). The project I'm using to figure out how to solve my issue is [this](https://github.com/enigmastudio/Enigma-Studio-4), once you've cloned you'll find an executable inside binary\estudio4.exe .  I've forgot to mention I'm using windows7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That reminds me of [Alexpux/MSYS2-packages issue 222](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/222#issuecomment-94114481):

> On Linux if you want to execute a file it must have the correct permissions.
>   By default a touched file will not have this, for security reasons.
>
> However Windows has a wrong-headed take on this, in that a file created with
>   New > Text Document automatically has execute permissions.
>
> So what looks to have happened in this case is that whoever created the batch files did so in a MSYS2 environment, hence the correct lack of execute
>   permissions.
>   What they did not do is `chmod +x` to correctly give these files
>   execute permission, as would have been done if the files were created with
>   Windows native tools.

So a simple `chmod +x` should be enough.

And then, [with Git 2.9.1 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285462/6309):

```
git add --chmod=+x -- afile
```

Comment: I'm impressed, it's awesome to know someone still look very old unanswered questions like this one and providing good answers. Thanks!