# Gradle build failed on Travis CI

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci

I used `filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'` because of encoding problems in `ProcessResources` in `build.gradle`. This build succeeded on my desktop, but failed on Travis CI. I guess this is the problem with Travis CI's Gradle. So I tried to update the version but could not find any information. Is this the problem with the Gradle version? If yes, what can I do?

Travis build error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/home/travis/build/EntryPointKR/K-Security/build.gradle' line: 43
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'K-Security'.
> No such property: filteringCharset for class: org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources_Decorated
```

Full travis build log: https://travis-ci.org/EntryPointKR/K-Security/builds/201771722

.travis.yml:

```
language: java
sudo: false
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - oracle-java8-installer
```

Problem code in build.gradle

```
processResources {
    filteringCharset = 'UTF-8' // Here
    filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            "version"   : project.version,
            "pluginName": rootProject.name,
            "mainClass" : "cloud.swiftnode.ksecurity.KSecurity",
            "author"    : "EntryPoint"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely due to a mismatch between your gradle version and the gradle version installed in the java image. [It was introduced in Gradle 2.14](https://docs.gradle.org/2.14-rc-1/release-notes.html#configuration-of-character-encoding-when-filtering-files-in-a-copyspec). The easiest fix is to use gradle wrapper to enforce the same version in both environments.

Simply add the wrapper task:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.3'
}
```

It should be possible to run `gradle wrapper` in `before_install`, or simply bundle the gradle-wrapper jar with your project. [Travis CI will detect gradle wrapper](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/#Default-script-Command) and use `gradlew` instead of `gradle`.

If you are using Windows on your local machine, [make sure you commit the `gradlew` script with executable flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691202/how-to-create-file-execute-mode-permissions-in-git-on-windows).