# Why does Travis CI edit my files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, travis-ci

I'm new to Travis CI and I simply want to understand why and what is going on here. I've followed the instructions for setup in their documentation to the best of my ability. What I've got is:

- My Rails code on Github
- Travis CI that build my repo as soon as it is pushed to the github branch master.
- A Heroku app to where Travis CI deploys the code if the build is successful.

What I can't grasp is why I get this when the build is finished:

```
HEAD detached from 2a3b308
Changes not staged for commit:
.......
modified:   script/travis.sh

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

   vendor/bundle/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I do a `before_install: - chmod +x script/travis.sh` in my .travis.yml and I get `chmod +x script/travis.sh` in my build log. I have git version 2.7.4

Why is my `script/travis.sh` edited? Should I add those changes or is something wrong in my setup? In the `script/travis.sh` I've got some minor commands to be executed before the build, setting up my Github identity and such.

Why is this folder `vendor/bundle/` added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to add a git diff step to see the nature of the change, but check your travis logs: if you see

```
chmod a+x travis.sh
```

That means your original `travis.sh` script was not added as executable.

In your repo, do a (with [Git 2.9.1+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285462/6309)):

```
git add --chmod=+x script/travis.sh
git commit -m "Make travis.sh executable"
git push
```

Then check again if travis still displays your file as modified after a build.

---

Regarding `vendor/bundle/`, it is not "added", simply generated and untracked, which means your repo is not modified.
See [Travis/Cache Bundle](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#Bundler)

> On Ruby and Objective-C projects, installing dependencies via Bundler can make up a large portion of the build duration. Caching the bundle between builds drastically reduces the time a build takes to run.
>
> If you have custom Bundler arguments, and these include the `--path` option, Travis CI will use that path. If `--path` is missing but `--deployment` is present, it will use `vendor/bundle`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do a `before_install: - chmod +x script/travis.sh` in my .travis.yml and I get `chmod +x script/travis.sh` in my build log. I have git version 2.7.

Comment: Update: That fixed the problem with the `travis.sh` being modified. Now it's only the `vendor/bundle/` being added.

Comment: Thanks. So in theory I don't have to do anything about it, right? But I think it look pretty ugly having that output. Can I filter it out somehow, or do I just have to accept that this is how it's going to be?

Comment: @bork yes: add `vendor/bundle` to your `.gitignore` (the add, commit and push). That way, the travis git status at the end won't mention it.