# Release script fails with "/bin/sh: 1: ./release-tasks.sh: Permission denied"

Tags: heroku

I followed article

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#specifying-release-phase-tasks

to configure to run a script during release step.

unfortunately the release results in the following error (*Release Log*):

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./release-tasks.sh: Permission denied
```

how can I fix this?

---

my `Procfile`:

```
release: ./release-tasks.sh
web: gunicorn ph.wsgi --preload --log-file -
```

`release-tasks.sh` (simplified):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py migrate --noinput
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git ignores most file permissions, but it does track the executable bit. Make your script executable and check it in, e.g.

```sh
chmod +x release-tasks.sh
git add release-tasks.sh
git commit -m "Make release-tasks.sh executable"
```

Then deploy as normal.

---

On Windows, you won't have `chmod`. Use [the `--chmod` option to `git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---chmod-x) instead:

```sh
git add --chmod=+x release-tasks.sh
git commit -m "Make release-tasks.sh executable"
```

Comment: How does one do that on windows (which doesn't have `chmod`)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, [`git add` has a `--chmod` option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21691202/354577). Skip the `chmod` line here and use `--chmod` in the second line: `git add --chmod=+x release-tasks.sh`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Awesome, thank you