# Restore a shell script file (.sh) in git

Tags: bash, git, shell

I am working on a project with a shell script file (let's say `a.sh`) in it.

I clone the repo on Windows and accidentally run `a.sh`. Then, when I run `git status` in git bash, I got the following information

```
git status
on branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file> ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore <file> ..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified: a.sh
```

Obviously, I do not want this `a.sh` to be changed, and I follow the hint with

```
git restore a.sh
```

However, when I run `git status` again, I still got the same information that `a.sh` was modified.
I also tried another way by stage and commit this file with `git commit -am "restore sh"`, then try to reset this file by `git restore head^ a.sh`. The result is still the same.

So I was wondering if there are any methods to tackle this problem?

FYI, according to my colleagues, `a.sh` is used for killing idle python thread. When I `git diff` this file, it shows that

```
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

I am not so familiar with shell script, so I am not sure if this information will be helpful.

Comment: Something seems to be changing the shell scripts permissions.

Comment: I've never used `git restore`. I would have used `git checkout a.sh`, which is what `git` used to recommend.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes

Comment: @chepner https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore is new, and replaces part of `git checkout`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Given that it is experimental and doesn't appear to provide any advantage over `checkout` in this case, I would stick with `checkout`.

Comment: It's experimental? The git docs don't say that it is.

Comment: @chepner I actually tried `git checkout a.sh`, but it still doesn't work out.

Comment: @evolutionxbox The link you posted did. Maybe it's not considered experimental in a version of `git` that actually recommends its use.

Comment: @chepner smdh. It totally does. How did I miss that?

Comment: @kofemann Thanks for the link, it worked!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes)

Comment: @chepner (and others): I'm not a developer-of-Git, and they are indeed all marked "experimental", but at this point, it's pretty likely that they'll remain. The basic observation is that the existing `git checkout` has safe modes (check out branch name) and unsafe modes (check out file name, overwrites and discards work-in-progress) and that you can't necessarily tell which mode any given `git checkout` might use. So the command got split into the safe `git switch` and the unsafe `git restore`. Since then, `git restore` has acquired options that let it do a few things `git checkout` can't.

Comment: This is not precisely a duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/21691202/1256452

Comment: Try `git checkout -- a.sh` to discard changes to a.sh

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Looks like you have not pushed any of your changes to "master" (remote).

So, you can do:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will undo whatever you have done at origin (i.e. you computer) to match your last "pushed" version on remote (i.e. before you started any of this).

Good Luck.