# "ChromeDriver is not executable" error when run GitLab pipeline

Tags: java, gitlab-ci, cucumber-junit

I am only starting to use GitLab as CI tool.
I have created autotests using stack: Java, Cucumber, Maven.
I have created gitlab-ci.yml with next settings:

```yaml
image: maven:latest
stages:
  - test
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn clean test -Dtest=RunCucumberTest
```

[yml example](https://share.getcloudapp.com/6quZ7BLO)

But Pipeline is failed with next errors:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /builds/<user>/cucumber-testing/./src/drivers/chromedriver_99.exe
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at seleniumActions.ActionWithElement.setUp(ActionWithElement.java:24)
    at stepDefinition.Hooks.setUp(Hooks.java:14)
```

How do I set up ChromeDriver for gitlab in my .yml file?

Comment: IS `/builds/<user>/cucumber-testing/./src/drivers/chromedriver_99.exe` executable?  My guess is that that path does not exist, and it is that "<user>" component of the path that is the problem.  Is that an actual directory name?  I'm assuming not.  If not, then it appears that something was supposed to have expanded "<user>" to the something else in that path, but failed to.

Comment: Which operating system is your job running on? Remember you can't execute windows executables on Unix.

Comment: I can not understand exactly where this path to .exe file was generated. In my project 'chromedriver_99.exe' file is located on './src/drivers/chromedriver_99.exe' path.
https://share.getcloudapp.com/xQuqegyJ

When I run test from IDE  - everything is ok

Comment: I am running on Windows 10

Comment: @tester but what operating system is your gitlab job running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitLab docker jobs execute in Linux docker containers. Your executable (`.exe` file) is a win32 binary and cannot be used in jobs running in Linux containers.

Download the linux [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and specify that file instead.

Comment: I have replaced  chromedriver.exe with linux chromedriver , but error is still present
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /builds/<my_username>/cucumber-testing/./src/drivers/chromedriver

Comment: @tester you must also set the executable bit on the file. You can either [do this with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691202/how-to-create-file-execute-mode-permissions-in-git-on-windows) or you can run `chmod +x ./src/drivers/chromedriver` as part of your GitLab job

Comment: if I understood correctly I have added "chmod +x ./src/drivers/chromedriver" to gitlab-ci.yml https://share.getcloudapp.com/L1uRxQL4

Comment: after pipeline running next error is shown
https://share.getcloudapp.com/JruOzqNE

Comment: @tester this sounds like a second question and probably should be asked separately.