# How to fix heroku build.sh permissin denied Error in Angular App

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I am deploying my Angular application and getting this error:

```
sh: 1: ./heroku.build.sh: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! givebrite@1.0.2 heroku-postbuild: `./heroku.build.sh
```

package.json

```json
    "heroku-postbuild": "./heroku.build.sh"
```

heroku.build.sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

usage() {
  echo "OVERVIEW: Build apps according to BUILD_ENV value. Meant to be used for Heroku deployment"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" = '-h' ] || [ "$1" = '--help' ]; then
  usage
fi

(
  if [ "$BUILD_ENV" ]; then
    ng build $BUILD_ENV --configuration $ENVIRONMENT && ng run $BUILD_ENV:server:$ENVIRONMENT
  else
    echo "Error: no build config for BUILD_ENV value '$BUILD_ENV'"
    exit 1
  fi
)
```

How to fix this error?

I removed `node_modules` and deleted the `heroku.build.sh` but still it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows this will work

In a terminal, I ran `git add --chmod=+x heroku.build.sh`
Then `git commit -m "Updated permission"`
Finally `git push`

Answer (score 1):

chmod +x heroku.build.sh in a right directory will solve this issue.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do that on the server, but that won't work here. That file needs to be executable at _build_ time, and `chmod`ding it will only work until the next dyno restart due to Heroku's ephemeral filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

1. You'll need to make that file executable locally, first.

   - If you're on a unixy type system you can do something like this:

     ```bash
     chmod +x path/to/heroku.build.sh
     ```
   - If you're on a Windows machine you'll need [a different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21691202/354577).
2. Then, commit that change and then redeploy.