# Can't commit update-index on Windows

Tags: windows, git, openshift

I have a executable file called `post_deploy` that's run on my OpenShift gear after a push, but it wasn't executable so I ran:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy
```

But every time I did a `git add` to commit the file, the file would loose the executable permission. If I tried to do a `commit`, git would tell me there was nothing to commit. I eventually had to pop over to Cygwin to get it to work, but how can I get this to work in Window's Command Prompt?

Comment: The update wasn't enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Git version: [with Git 2.9.1, you can add with chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285435/6309)

```
git add --chmod=+x -- yourFile
```

Also check the value of `git config core.filemode`. I suspect it should be false (which is expected in an environment which does not support executable bit).
Still, the `add --chmod=+x` should be enough to record that executable bit in the Git repo.

Finally, clone your repo in a Linux/Cygwin environment and check if the file is not *already* executable there.

---

The [OP NicholasJohn16](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903619/nicholasjohn16) reports [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403572/cant-commit-update-index-on-windows/39405573?noredirect=1#comment67097123_39405573) using "[How do I remove files saying “old mode 100755 new mode 100644” from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1257592/6309)" to solve the issue.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.5 so that might be the issue. Will update and try this if it happens again.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to work after upgrading to 2.10.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 And (on Windows) the latest 2.10.1? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.10.1.windows.1) released two days ago?

Comment: Was able to actually fix my issue with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha so maybe it was a different issue I was having.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 OK. I have included the link and your comment in the answer for more visibility. Was it the `git config core.filemode false`?