# How do you make a Concourse Linux Machine read executable files? (chmod style)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, continuous-integration, concourse

I am trying to get my Concourse CI Linux VM to run a shell script. But i keep getting the same error:

[image]

I fixed this locally (non VM, on a Mac) with `chmod +x path/filename.sh` to make it executable and adding `!#/bin/sh` to the shell script.

But i dont know how to get Concourse/VM to know that it's an executable? Is there a chmod command i should put into the task.sh? or the task.yml? Help!

my Concourse CI `pipeline.yml`

```
resources:
- name: my-git-repo
  type: git
  source:
    uri: git@github.com:org-name/my-git-repo.git
    branch: master
    private_key: {{git-private-key}}
- name: my-task
  type: git
  source:
    uri: git@gist.github.com:blahblahblah12345678910blah.git
    private_key: {{git-private-key}}

jobs:
- name: job-build-app
  plan:
  - get: my-git-repo
    trigger: true
  - get: task
  - task: run-build
    file: my-task/task.yml
```

My `task.yml`:

```
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: busybox}

inputs:
- name: my-task

run:
  path: ./my-task/task.sh
```

My `task.sh`:

```
!#/bin/sh
echo this is my task shell script
```

I expected this to just echo/log out the string above.

Instead i get the 500/permission denied error at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file in the git repo has to be `chmod +x`ed. You're gonna have a hard time doing that in a Gist, since that can't be set in the UI.

You could clone the gist, `chmod +x`, and re-push, or change your task to run `bash my-task/task.sh` instead, which won't require it to be executable:

```
run:
  path: bash
  args: [./my-task/task.sh]
```

Comment: Thanks @alexsuraci yeah i ended up fixing by cloning the gist, adding a new file locally, chmod'ing it, then pushing it. Worked straight away.

Comment: You can also use `git update-index --chmod=+x task.sh` to change the `chmod` state, or automate that as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14267441/1262901).