# How to automatically "chmod" a file in PyCharm/IntelliJ with a particular extension?

Tags: bash, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, file-extension

##### Background

I'm maintaining a repo in which I create many small `bash` files containing tiny code snippets.
To create these files, I use the `Right Click -> New -> File` interaction in PyCharm/IntelliJ quite often:
[image: Create New File]

These files are automatically created with the `rw-rw-r-- (664)` permissions.
So every time, I have to start a terminal, and execute `chmod 700 somefile.sh` to make them executable.

##### The Question

It would be wonderful to automatically set the permissions of files with a certain extension in IntelliJ/PyCharm.
I don't want all my files to be executable, just the files with a `.sh` extension.
Is there a way I configure this?

Comment: There is File Permissions plug-in: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16238-file-permissions. It's open source so you can probably modify it to perform it automatically on certain actions (like VCS update).

Comment: If you are using Git, this can be automated with Git hooks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710807/104891.

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11217-git-extended-update-index plug-in claims to support --chmod=+x on git update-index.

Comment: Thanks, @CrazyCoder! Not quite what I was looking for because I'd like them to be executable before adding them to git. However, this is not a crazy start ;-). Upvoted because they are good suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

A non-elegant solution and potentially problematic would be to have a bash script in the background checking contents of a specific directory for specific filenames and applying `chmod 700` on those.

I strongly suggest a special directory - to minimize the risk of this script affecting other/unexpected files.

You'd need to set it to sleep for a few seconds so that it doesn't take up too much of your CPU time.

It could look something like this:

background_chmod.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILESPEC="*.sh"
DIRPATH=/some/special/path/

while [ 0 ] :
do
    find $DIRPATH -name $FILESPEC -type f -exec chmod 700 {} \;
    sleep 10;  # tweak this to your requirements
done
```

You could then put it in your .bashrc file (if you are using bash) to execute when you log on.
Additional line in your .bashrc would be:
/path_to_script/background_chmod.sh &

Rememeber to:

```
 chmod +x /path_to_script/background_chmod.sh
```

IMPORTANT: I have no means of testing the above. Please test this on some test files before implementing! Use at your own risk!

Comment: Upvoted because this worked and you properly addressed the risks and limitations. Didn't accept it because I'm hoping for a more elegant solution. Regardless, you made a quality contribution. Thanks!.